# This MySQL syntax is invalid but works

Tags: mysql, syntax

According to [MySQL 5.5 documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html), the valid syntax for an UPDATE is the following:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references
SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
[WHERE where_condition]
```

In our code we found this request:

```
UPDATE eMail SET Actif = 0 AND FKClient = 122;
```

The table is Innodb on a MySQL 5.5 and `Actif` is tinyint(1) nullable.

As far as I know this syntax is invalid and should not execute since the `AND` comparison is not permitted in a `SET` statement.

If you execute the code, all `eMail` rows will be set to `Actif = 0`.

Why does my `UPDATE` request work?

Comment: What type is `Actif`?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention: tinyint(1) nullable. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure it is. It's parsed as:

```
UPDATE eMAIL SET Active = (0 AND FKCLient = 122)
```

`FKClient= 122` will be a boolean comparison, returning true/false, so it becomes

```
UPDATE eMAIL SET Active = (0 AND bool)
```

`0 AND anything` is `0`, so..

```
... SET Active = 0
```

Comment: I'm not quite there yet.  You never stated how the expression in parentheses resolves to zero.  Does `false` resolve to 0 in MySQL?  Is there some sort of bitwise AND going on here?

Comment: This is exactly what is going on. Nice explanation.